# Was the original Star Wars film originally called "The Star Wars"?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, behind-the-scenes

I have heard that the original film was to be "The Star Wars" and somewhere along the line they dropped "The".

One person says they have seen a windbreaker or T-shirt in a Star Wars collection that has the familiar logo and includes "The" that came from somebody involved in the film.

**Was the title originally "The Star Wars"?**

Comment: *The Star Wars: First Draft* was the first title of the idea, and later transformed into *Adventures of the Starkiller, Saga I: The Star Wars*, which in turn was turned into *The Star Wars: From The Adventures of Luke Starkiller*

Comment: Then, Lucas had lunch with Sean Parker...

Comment: The phrasing in the question body, "was to be", matches the answer about a first draft, but the phrasing in the title, "originally called", implies to me that it would have had to have been released under that title for the answer to be 'yes'.

Answer (score 78):

### Yes, this is correct

One of Lucas' earliest drafts of the script, penned in 1974, [sold at auction](http://natedsanders.com/star-wars-original-1974-script---the-star-wars---lot16536.aspx) in 2013; that script bore the title "The Star Wars" (click to embiggen):

[image]

And fan-made scans of the early script drafts continue to support this (click to embiggen all images):

- The 1973 treatment, titled "The Star Wars"

  [image]
- The 1974 rough draft script, which bears the title "Star Wars" on the outside cover but "The Star Wars" on the inside:

  [image]
- The 1975 second draft, titled "Adventures of the Starkiller (episode one) The Star Wars":

  [image]

However, I'm not aware of any official merchandise bearing this title; certainly there wouldn't have been any at the time, because merchandise production was famously limited before the film was actually in theatres, and the title had changed by that time; Peter Mayhew (Chewbacca) posted some images of his copy of the 1976 script [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/TheWookieeRoars/status/700102566688862211/), where the definite article had already been dropped (click to embiggen):

[image]

Comment: +1 for embiggen, one of the very best words not in the English language.

Comment: It's a very cromulent word

Comment: Bah humbug. Pfui.

Comment: A Stanford University physicist managed to slip "embiggen" into an actual scientific journal article. Incidentally, this article was called "Gauge/gravity duality and meta-stable dynamical supersymmetry breaking", so I can't imagine "embiggen" was the biggest hurdle to overcome in order to understand it.

Comment: So people looking through cinema listings at the time would just have seen "Star Wars", correct?

Comment: @CHEESE *embiggen* is being used regularly; it probably can be defined as being in the English language by now.

Comment: -1 for no freehand circles

Comment: I didn't know Utapau and the Whills had been (intended to be) in the story from the start.

Comment: @TheDarkLord Yes.

Comment: What's wrong with "enlarge"? It's easier to say, spell, write and type than "embiggen".

Comment: @DepressedDaniel: Why use a humdrum, stodgy, plebian, platitudinous word like "enlarge" that when you can use spine-tingling, hair-raising, provocative, flashy words like "embiggen"?

Comment: @tonysdg You mean why not use vertecreep, coifflifting, exterioragous, macromedish words like embiggen? Only so people can understand you ...

Comment: Am I the only one to notice that the title in the picture of the presumed 1974 document looks like Times New Roman, the default font of the famous default word processor that did not exist in 1974? The rest of the document is plain typewriter. Those kind of documents at the time were fully typed on a typewriter, weren't they? IOW, is that photograph legit ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFio9m.jpg The other, presumed from 1976 looks more legit https://i.stack.imgur.com/hk8ivm.jpg

Comment: @StéphaneGourichon IMHO the rest of the page is in a modern typewriter font rather than actual typewritten text. I think that picture is a mock-up of what someone thought the script might have looked like.

Comment: @jwg The image is taken directly from [the auction lot page](http://natedsanders.com/star-wars-original-1974-script---the-star-wars---lot16536.aspx). I'm not a collector, but the auctioneer seems reputable, and I'm inclined to take them at their word. But, just for you, I went and found some less clean-looking images as further evidence

Comment: @StéphaneGourichon: The top portion was clearly not done on a typewriter, but so what?  There are a variety of devices that would have been available for purchase or use (at a graphics arts shop) at reasonable cost in the early 1970s that could produce text like that, including pantograph tracers and rubber stamps in different fonts [combined with careful effort to hand-fill the letters].  Producing that title would have been a lot more work back then than today, but for an aspiring writer to invest such effort would hardly seem implausible.

Comment: The original storyboards for the opening shots show the film's title as "The Star Wars". Don't have my storyboards book to hand, so not sure of the date. Example here: https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a5/cc/98/a5cc9804f2dd47619f41f6977d70768f.jpg

Answer (score 4):

The "Visual Encyclopedia of Science Fiction" is notable for surveying the field just before "The Star Wars " came out. Published in 1976, it's an excellent guide to fandom the moment before Star Wars broke, and the upcoming movie is always referred to as "The Star Wars".

Answer (score 4):

Bonus: Dark Horse produced an eight-volume comic series in 2013 called "The Star Wars", based on the original script treatment and incorporating all the stark differences between the original concept and the 1977 movie

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Star_Wars

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE, you haven't seemed to answer the question but instead provided a comment. I recommend you either edit it to include an answer to *Was the title originally "The Star Wars"?* or delete your answer and provide it as a comment to the question.

Comment: Unless you mean to say that the title of the comic series indicates that it was originally called *The Star Wars*, in that case it should probably made a little clearer.